# Why can't I get the exit values of a command in this bash script?

Tags: shell, exit

So I was writing this little nautilus script for transcoding video into mp3:

```
#! /bin/bash -x

if [ -z "$1" ]
    then
    zenity --warning --text="Error - No file selected !"
    exit 1
fi

BASEFILENAME=${1%.*}

exec ffmpeg -i "$1" -ab 256k "$BASEFILENAME.mp3" &&

if [ "$?" -eq 0 ]
    then
    zenity --info --text="Converting successful"
    exit
fi
```

The  problem is, though the ffmpeg command is executed successfully the `if [ "$?" -eq 0 ]`

seems not to get triggered. Why is that? Is the `&&` wrong  or is it something else?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The only way that statement can be reached is if the `exec` itself fails; if it succeeds, the `ffmpeg` command replaces the shell completely.  (Pedantically, the `&&` will fail in that case also so it can't be reached at all.)  You don't want to `exec` it, just run it.

Comment: I see, and without the `&&` after the ffmpeg command it actually works. I still have one more question, if it's okay at this place - is there a way to display the stdout and stderr of ffmpeg somewhere without using a terminal window? Like in zenity f.e.

Comment: You'd want to capture it with the `$()` construct into a variable, then pass that variable to `zenity`. Watch out for quoting, and `zenity` in my experience uses PanGo so you need to replace `<`, `&`, `>` with `&lt;`, `&amp;`, `&gt;` respectively.

Answer (score 5):

The `exec command` statement replaces the current shell with `command`.
That is, your script actaully terminates at line `exec ffmpeg ...`;
remaining lines would be executed if and only if the `ffmpeg` command
is not found on your PATH (or it cannot be launched for other reasons).

You can get more details on the `exec` bash built-in by typing `help exec` at the bash command prompt:

```
$ help exec
exec: exec [-cl] [-a name] [command [arguments ...]] [redirection ...]
    Replace the shell with the given command.

    Execute COMMAND, replacing this shell with the specified program.
    ARGUMENTS become the arguments to COMMAND.  If COMMAND is not specified,
    any redirections take effect in the current shell.
    [...]
```

Answer (score 1):

[According to this](http://ss64.com/bash/exec.html) `exec` replaces the shell with the command you specify.  So your script is never getting to the commands past the `exec`.

You don't need `exec`.  Just specify the command.

Answer (score 0):

You may keep the `exec` command if you put it into a subshell:

```
- exec ffmpeg -i "$1" -ab 256k "$BASEFILENAME.mp3" &&
+ (exec ffmpeg -i "$1" -ab 256k "$BASEFILENAME.mp3") &&
```

Comment: I see, but isn't the `&&` still wrong there?

Comment: Yes. And what's the point of keeping the `exec`?